# SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER

Tags: android, android-intent, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, google-api-client

I get the error `SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent` but looks like it do not have good solution after searching many topics.

Please help me,

Thanks,

p/s :

I'm make sure I used correct `SENDER_ID` as project number was defined at `Google API Console` and correct `package name`.

**Error :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
            at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1785)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:480)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.e(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
            at controller.RegisterGCMClientAsync.doInBackground(RegisterGCMClientAsync.java:62)
            at controller.RegisterGCMClientAsync.doInBackground(RegisterGCMClientAsync.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Manifest.xml file:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="app.cloudstringers" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.Cloudstringers"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ui.fragment.RegisterWithAccountsFragment" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <permission
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Receiver GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="app.cloudstringers" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Service GCM -->
    <service
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.GcmIntentService" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

</application>
```

**SOLUTION**
I put wrong lines. Should put `<use-permission>` tag outside of `<application>` tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change to this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
      <permission
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.Cloudstringers"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ui.fragment.RegisterWithAccountsFragment" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



    <!-- Receiver GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="app.cloudstringers" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Service GCM -->
    <service
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="app.cloudstringers.GcmIntentService" />



</application>
```

You should put `<use-permission>` tag outside of `<application>` tag.

Answer (score 6):

You should check if play store can work or not.
If it does not work, it can not start google service.