# Unable to Register Android App with GCM : Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

Building An App using the Android Studio.
There is some issue in the App configuration that throws a java.lang.SecurityException.

The project is stored in https://github.com/snambi/gcm_register

The AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <permission android:name="org.antennae.gcmtests.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="org.antennae.gcmtests.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyGcmIntentService" android:exported="false" ></service>
</application>
```

The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    // GcmWrapper startup

    GcmWrapper gcmwrapper = new GcmWrapper(context);
    String registrationId = gcmwrapper.getRegId();

    Toast.makeText(context, "REG_ID = "+ registrationId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

The code the registers with GCM ( GcmWrapper )

```
public class GcmWrapper {

private Context context;

public GcmWrapper( Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public String getRegId(){
    String regId = getRegIdFromPrefs();
    if( regId == null || regId.trim().equals("") ){
        registerWithGcm();
    }

    return regId;
}

public String getRegIdFromPrefs(){

    String registrationId=null;

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_ANTENNAE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    registrationId  = preferences.getString(Constants.PREF_REGISTRATION_ID, "");

    int appVersion = AppVersionUtils.getAppVersion(context);
    SharedPreferences prefs =PreferencesUtil.getSharedPreferences(context);
    if( appVersion != AppVersionUtils.getSavedAppVersion( prefs ) ){
        // if different, clear the saved regId
        registrationId=null;
    }

    return registrationId;
}

public void registerWithGcm(){
    GcmRegistrationTask registerTask = new GcmRegistrationTask(context, Constants.PROJECT_ID);
    registerTask.execute();
}

public static class GcmRegistrationTask extends AsyncTask{

    private Context context;
    private String projectId;

    public GcmRegistrationTask( Context context, String projectId ){
        this.context = context;
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        String regId = null;

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        try {
            regId = gcm.register( projectId );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return regId;
    }
  }
}
```

Exception Thrown

```
06-18 22:54:01.737  24266-24317/org.antennae.gcmtests.gcmtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1412)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1394)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zzx(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
        at org.antennea.gcm.GcmWrapper$GcmRegistrationTask.doInBackground(GcmWrapper.java:70)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: That's odd, because the error is that your app doesn't have the permission "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE", however you do declare it in your manifest. Can you confirm that the apk you're running actually requests this permissiong? Try running "adb shell dumpsys package <your.app.package.name>" and make sure this permission is listed.

Comment: @morepork great suggestion. the dumpsys doesn't show the permissions.     grantedPermissions:
      android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
      android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
      android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
      android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
      android.permission.INTERNET    I'm using AndroidStudio. I have tried uninstalling the app manually. Still the permission is getting through. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was an issue for other people as well (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399845/securityexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-act-com-google-android-c2)).

I checked the official GCM docs and indeed can verify that you'll need to place `uses-permission` outside the application tag.

By the way, it looks like you are using the deprecated C2DM libraries. You might want to use the [latest one](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) to avoid the hassle of migrating later on. There is a sample project provided in the docs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The key is "permissions" are moved outside of "Application". Now I'm able to register the application and the security exception is gone. Basically the AndroidManifest.xml was wrong. Eclipse ADT will show errors if incorrect xml is created. OTOH, AndroidStudio doesn't show errors when the XML is incorrect. It fails when the app is started. Thanks for the answer.