# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent error in android api level 23

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im using a service in an application for smart card reader
but i'm getting an error in **android 5.0** and above

```
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Not allowed to start service Intent { 
act=com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.backendipc
 pkg=com.theobroma.cardreadermanager } without permission 
com.hidglobal.ia.omnikey.service.permission.SMARTCARDIO
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.smartcard">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.hidglobal.ia.omnikey.service.permission.SMARTCARDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>
```

This service is comminicating with hid omnikey driver installed in device.

Which is available here : https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/16553

How can i sove this issue ?

**Manifest of service application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager" platformBuildVersionCode="15" platformBuildVersionName="4.0.4-1406430">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<permission android:label="Access HID Global Omnikey Base Service" android:name="com.hidglobal.ia.omnikey.service.permission.SMARTCARDIO" android:protectionLevel="dangerous" android:description="Allows this app to receive smart card events and to access the HID Global Omnikey Base Service." />
<uses-permission android:name="com.hidglobal.ia.omnikey.service.permission.SMARTCARDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application android:theme="null" android:label="CardReaderManager" android:icon="res/drawable-ldpi-v4/ic_hid_omnikey.png" android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.CardReaderApplication" android:logo="res/drawable-ldpi-v4/ic_hid_omnikey.png">
    <activity android:label="CardReaderManager" android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.CardReaderManagerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.BackendService" android:permission="com.hidglobal.ia.omnikey.service.permission.SMARTCARDIO" android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.backendservice" />
            <action android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.backendipc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.BackendServiceStarter">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:label="CardReaderInfo" android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.CardReaderInfoActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.theobroma.cardreadermanager.cardreaderinfoactivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Seems like you've not declared the service in your manifest. Do so.

Comment: @Vucko I don't have the source code of the service application

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399845/securityexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-act-com-google-android-c2

Comment: At work right now, I will check it out later if no one has answered

Comment: @AftabHussain Okay

Comment: @AftabHussain I have extracted the service apk and added the manifest to my question, have a look

Comment: @AftabHussain tried few changes in manifest, still no luck :(

Comment: Sorry. Got really busy yesterday. I'll check it out tonight :)

Comment: @AftabHussain okay, i have added the manifest of the service app, please have a look. :)

Comment: @AftabHussain there in an update : i have added intent.setAction and intent.setPackage to bindservice() function, now if i go to app settings and enable the permission manually it works. is there any other way ?

Comment: @JPS To be honest, I haven't worked with 3rd party services yet. But from what I know, your code seemed ok to me. I will have to ask a classmate of mine and hope he can do something about it.

Comment: @AftabHussain its working now, but only the problem is i have to enable the permission manually, is there any way to call requestPermissions() for third party services on android 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite old, but still some may find it helpful.
As a workaround, you may set target SDK in `build.gradle` to 22 or lower i.e. `targetSdkVersion 22`

This worked for me