# Android - firebase SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent?

Tags: android, firebase

I found a bug in my app when Using firebase

the problem only accrued when

1. install my app on emulator that don't have google play service
2. run the app
3. close the app
4. install google play (OPEN GAPPS on genymotion)
5. run app again !

in step 5 app will force close with

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: firebase-iid-executor
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 3520
    java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and indicate the line at which this error occurs.

Comment: I have this too and it's very rare. It's an edge case and probably won't be fixed.

Comment: If you have a bug to report with any part of Firebase, don't post it to Stack Overflow.  File a bug report instead.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @AlexMamo this error is not occurs in activity or class I just implement firebase in build.gradle and add "firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled" in manifest

Comment: @TheWanderer Look I think I solved this ! with just add <permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Answer (score 1):

Add this to permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: You can look at this question it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399845/securityexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-act-com-google-android-c2

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this with this in manifest

```
  <permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```